# 404 | not found error if I create any route rather than default one

Tags: laravel, view, routes

I installed Laravel latest version i.e v7 but when I try to change the route or create my own route that route is not working.

Here is the default route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**This is what I'm trying to hit URL in the browser:**
http://localhost/mobileshop/public/

This is working fine but when I try to change it or write my own route it shows error 404 | not found

This is what I'm trying when I get this error

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Or

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    dd("my own route");
    });
```

Both are not working what to do?

**This is what I'm trying to hit URL in the browser:**
http://localhost/mobileshop/public/login

I researched and found something here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/order-of-routes-in-webphp?page=1

but whatever they tell I don't think I'm doing that mistake, am I?

I'm using XAMPP.

I myself changed route, views, and many other things but still, I'm there at error 404.

When I stop XAMPP and run php artisan serve and use: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login URL in browser its working fine. So is there any issue in my XAMPP? If there is an issue in my XAMPP then why default route is working I'm not understanding.

Can anyone help me to issue and about how to use XAMPP rather than php artisan serve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after this chnage your url like this localhost/login not a localhost/

Comment: Can you read question again? I edit my question for your better understanding

Comment: ok. you are run wrong way use command  and your code perfectly right - 127.0.0.1:8000/login and default 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I'm using xampp not php artisan serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely because how you run your laravel, An easy way is that you may need to run this command at your root of your laravel and in the terminal you will get a `url` just use that and you should be fine.

```sh
php artisan serve
```

Working with xampp:

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a new line like: `127.0.0.1       yoursite.local`
2. Go to where xampp is installed under `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` Then add a virtual host in the bottom of the file like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "PATH_to_laravel_folder/public"  

ServerName yoursite.local  
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can access your route by typing: `yoursite.local/login` or `yoursite.local:80/login`

Comment: I'm not understanding Why I can't use xampp? can you please tell me

Comment: @AliBhutta I am not saying you can not use xampp, I am saying it's easy to use `artisan serve`, if you want to know how to use xampp you should change your question.

Comment: Thanks, can't you tell me here? mean is it necessary to ask in different question?

Comment: @AliBhutta you can modify your existing question, your question did not say anything about xampp.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

1. This '/login' is URL
2. This is blade.php 'welcome'
3. Use `php artisan serve` in cmd

**After Then you try 127.0.0.1:8000/login in browser**

Comment: I'm using xampp, it is necessary to use php artisan serve?